# django error :1146, "Table 'basic_project.topics_topic' doesn't exist"

Tags: python, django, pinax

> TemplateSyntaxError at /tribes/
>
> Caught an exception while rendering: (1146, "Table
>   'basic_project.topics_topic' doesn't exist")

Why?

Answer (score 2):

[Because.](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/#syncdb)

You have to run `syncdb` everytime you add a new app or model.

Comment: Note that this command has been deprecated since Django 1.7. Use `migrate` instead.